# Difference between txqueuelen and ethtool tx

Tags: linux, networking, rhel

What's the difference between the `txqueuelen` setting that can be applied with either:

```
ifconfig eth4 txqueuelen 5000
ip link set eth4 txqueuelen 5000
```

And the `tx` ring size setting that can be applied with:

```
ethtool -G eth4 tx 4096
```

How do these relate to the global `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem*` settings?

I'm on RHEL6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `net.core.wmem_default` and `wmem_max` settings control the initial and maximum sizes of TX socket buffers in bytes.  While the queue itself is just a linked list of `skb` pointers, the kernel also keeps track of the total byte-size consumed by the `skb`'s as they're added and removed from the socket buffer.  The `wmem_default` sysctl sets the default initial ceiling for new sockets (`net/core/sock.c:sock_init_data()`).  Applications are allowed to increase the size of their sockets' buffers and `wmem_max` is the ceiling for that functionality (`net/core/sock.c:sock_setsockopt()`).

When a packet has been removed from a socket buffer and finds its way through the kernel networks stack, it's placed on a transmission queue for an interface to wait to be loaded onto the NIC itself.  The `txqueuelen` set by the `ifconfig` or `ip` commands is number of frames allowed per kernel transmission queue for the queuing discipline (`net/sched/sch_generic.c:pfifo_fast_enqueue()`).

Finally, `ethtool -G` uses ioctl to set the number of ring entries for the ring buffer on the NIC itself.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm supposed to give a long drawn out explanation, but D[an Seimon already has](http://www.coverfire.com/articles/queueing-in-the-linux-network-stack/).  In short `txqueuelen` is the buffer size.  All the network packets fit in this buffer, whereas `tx` is the packet size of the IP Packet that goes in said buffer.  That is if I understand that post correctly.